# Calculate depth of indentation in model using two points?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, vector

Via Raycasting one can select a point on an GameObjects Collider. In the short visual two points are represented with small spheres denoting user selection. The desire is to calculate the depth of any spot in an models indentation. Current thought is to use a system in which the user selects a point within the depth of the indentation and a point outside of it than calculating the depth using Vector math.

As of now, the information available to us is the two points (Vectors) in space and the distance between them. How do we use the aforementioned data to calculate a point perpendicular to the point in the depth? Thought being if this point is calculable than the depth would be the distance between those two points. How to go about this, and is it feasible?

Visual:
[image: visual_clip]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that 2 points are enough. You, seeing the whole scene, know the planes where both points lie so you can see the direction of the shortest distance (perpendicular) segment. But just for two points there are infinitely many other valid planes going through them. The only thing you can say is that the depth is bound by the distance between those two points.

Consider following example: one point `A` is `(0,0,0)` and `B` is `(2,1,0)`. How deep is the indentation? The answer is: you don't know.

Assume first that the planes are (the plane `a` contains the point `A` and the plane `b` contains the point `B`):

- `a` is `X = 0` while `b` is `X = 2`. Then the indentation depth is clearly 2.
- `a` is `Y = 0` while `b` is `Y = 1`. Then the indentation depth is clearly 1.
- finally if `a` is `Z = 0` and `b` is `Z = 0`. Then the indentation depth is clearly 0.

Actually change the planes direction you can get any depth between `0` and the distance between `A` and `B`.

The only solution I see is to fix at least one of the two planes by selecting ***3*** points on that plane. And then the problem becomes trivial. Having 3 points you find the plane equation in a form of

```
a*x + b*y + c*z + d = 0
```

Then the distance from a point `(x1,y1,z1)` to that plane is

```
dist = (a*x1 + b*y1 + c*z1 + d)/sqrt(a^2+b^2+c^2)
```